# Network interfaces get stuck and need to turn off/on to resume traffic

Tags: ubuntu-18.04, debian-buster

I am using Asterisk on Ubuntu 18.04 and on Debian buster. The network interfaces (for SIP Signaling and RTP) get stuck after sometime (2-3 hours) and need to turn off/on the interfaces to resume the traffic.

H/W: HP Pro. DL380 and Dell PE R730 XD
OS: Ubuntu 18.04 and Debian buster
SIP Signaling IP: x.x.x.71 and RTP IP: x.x.x.199 communicating with same G/W x.x.x.1.

Have anyone got the similar issue or someone have any suggestion ?

Comment: what is "stuck"?

Comment: Network interfaces stop working and do not pass through the traffic until we turn off/on the interfaces.

Comment: Can you verify with tcpdump that they are really stuck while sending pings (ie: not just the SIP traffic)? Are there kernel messages (`dmesg`)?

Comment: Hi A.B, 
For the said two interfaces, we are using them specifically for VoIP (Lets say eth1 for SIP and eth2 for RTP/Media). One of the either interfaces stops/stuck, causing disruptions with the respective traffic. Let me verify with the tcpdump and will share the outcomes. 
I am using a script that pings the SIP and RTP/Media gateway IPs and restart the interface that stops to ping. Have gone through the dmesg but observed nothing in that.